Detect if browser can render HEIC image
Is there an easy way to detect if a browser can render HEIC image?
I can think of one way, render a pixel heic image and check the color of the pixel post render. Something like:
const myImg = new Image();
myImg.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
myImg.onload = () => {
  const context = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  context.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0);
  const {
    data
  } = context.getImageData(10, 10, 1, 1);
  console.log(data)
}
myImg.src = 'https://picsum.photos/200/300';

Wondering, if there is a better way?

load a larger picture and show it, transparent if desired, then check the naturalHeight once it loads, if <33 then it's an error placeholder.

As a simple first approximation you can assume NO, this should be correct in 80%+ of cases. Or test for Safari.

https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2020/12/coping-with-heic-in-the-browser/

@ScottMarcus I have already visited this. :) doesnt provide any info ab what I asked.

@teapot418, you are absolutely correct. I am just trying to find a way to be precise.

Using image.decode seems to work. I can't test since I don't Safari


const jpg = new Image();
jpg.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
jpg.src = 'https://picsum.photos/200/300';
jpg.decode().then(
    () => console.log("JPEG supported"), 
    () => console.log("JPEG NOT supported")
);

const heic = new Image();
heic.src = 'https://icanhazcode.com/image1.heic';
heic.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
heic.decode().then(
    () => console.log("HEIC supported"), 
    () => console.log("HEIC NOT supported")
);




@Kaiido - I thought it did (my site) ... it does now :p

Thanks, this is works
